# python numpy creating logical array

Tags: python, numpy

I have large numpy array and trying to create logical (1, 0) array from it. For example,

```
a=np.array((2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,2.0))
a==2.0
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I want `1.0` (float/double) for all `2.0`s in `a`. `a==2.0` gives array of `bool`, but not `1.0` float. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want the non-`2.0` elements to be? `False`? `0.0`? Their value in `a`? Also, you should be wary of directly comparing floating point numbers without accounting for [floating point error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> (a == 2).astype(float)
array([1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(a==2.0) * 1
```

True multiplied by number will be equal to that number and False multiplied by number will be equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

Just do `a = float(a)`, you can also use `numpy` to convert the type

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[1.0 if i else False for i in r]
```